# Getting a longer stacktrace from FastMM?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, stack-trace, fastmm

When FastMM logs a memory leak it includes a stacktrace going back 9 calls. Problem is that the stacktrace is too general to locate the problem easily. The last function call in the trace is called at least 50 times and the object leaked is a very common one.

What can I do to make the stacktrace longer?

Tips to locate leaks more easily are of course welcome, the objects leaked are mostly interfaces, so it's something with cross-referencing or _ReleaseRef not called.

I'm on Delphi 7, using the FastMM492.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change the `StackTraceDepth` constant in [*FastMM4.pas*](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4/blob/aa51f3e0c38d506e68b25c41288c9e9a58be15a1/FastMM4.pas#L1456).

Comment: Ahh, nice one, I will try it tomorrow. I only checked the .inc file.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [FastMM4 Options Interface](http://jedqc.blogspot.com/2007/07/new-fastmm4-options-interface.html) from Jed Software. It is a freeware application to configre FastMM

Comment: It looks like that program only adjusts the conditional-compilation options from *FastMM4Options.inc*.